# Authenticate Symfony2 REST API with Google Account

Tags: api, rest, symfony, google-account, fosoauthserverbundle

I'm working with Symfony2 and FOSOauthServerBundle in a REST API. I would wish that some user could log in by a client app using their Google Account, for instance.

From my REST server, by web, I can log in with my Google Account (using HWIOauthBundle), but I need to send to the client app an access_token (like FOSOauthServerBundle does).

I'm interested on persist the access_token that Google send to me in my data base and at the same time, send to the client app the json message {'access_token': 'XMekfmns.... } with Google's (and now my REST API too) access_token.

I don't know if my approach is right. Any ideas?

(sorry for my english ;-) )

Thank you very much

Comment: Why send the google token to the client?  Seems like that would all be server side.

Comment: Ok. You're right. So I need make an access_token (to send to the client app) after get the Google token (like FOSOauthServerBundle does when receive the request with the query parameter "...&grant_type=password&...")

Comment: That is what I do.  Your client code should not care about the server side authentication/authorization process.  It just gets a token and sends it back with each request.

Answer (score 0):

This is my (dirty) solution, but I hope people understand what I want to.

From the client side, the user send the request to get authorization from the google account (I'm using Symfony2 with HWIOauthBundle)

http://myserver.com/connect/google

This present the Google login form. The user fill the form and submit it. If success exists, there will be a redirect to myserver.com where the user will logged.

I catch the event onAuthenticationSuccess ...

```
<?php

namespace App\Bundle\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request,
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse,
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;

class SecurityHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{

    private $router;

    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();

        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('api_get_token', array(
            'clientRandomId' => '5ewv02jcis08wsgggk4wow4so0gokco0g4s8kkoc4so4s0gw4c'
        )));
    }
    #clientRandomId value is an existing value in the table (entity) Client ...
    #... in the database.
}
```

... to redirect to a Controller where it will generate an access_token and refresh_token, where they will be saved in the database. At the end, it will be sent a json response to the user, like FOSOauthServerBundle does.

```
<?php

namespace App\Bundle\Controller\Api;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller,
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse,
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController,
    FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Route,
    FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\NamePrefix,
    FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Prefix;

use FOS\RestBundle\Routing\ClassResourceInterface;

use App\Bundle\Entity\AccessToken;
use App\Bundle\Entity\RefreshToken;

class TokenController extends FOSRestController implements ClassResourceInterface {

#this method has the route named 'api_get_token' 

public function getAction($clientRandomId)
{
    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

    #control if user exist ...

    #We force the loggout 
    $this->container->get('security.context')->setToken(null);

    $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();

    $client = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Client')->findOneBy(array('randomId' => $clientRandomId));

    #control if client exist ...

    $expiresAt = time() + 3600;

    $accessToken = new AccessToken;
    $accessToken->setClient($client);
    $accessToken->setToken('access_token'); #This is only an example
    $accessToken->setExpiresAt($expiresAt);
    $accessToken->setUser($user);

    $refreshToken = new RefreshToken;
    $refreshToken->setClient($client);
    $refreshToken->setToken('refresh_token'); #This is only an example
    $refreshToken->setExpiresAt($expiresAt);
    $refreshToken->setUser($user);

    $em->persist($accessToken);
    $em->persist($refreshToken);
    $em->flush();

    $jsonData = array(
        'access_token' => $accessToken->getToken(),
        'expires_in' => 3600,
        'token_type' => 'bearer',
        'scope' => null,
        'refresh_token' => $refreshToken->getToken()
    );

    $response = new JsonResponse($jsonData);

    return $response;
}}
```

I know this is not the best solution but maybe it guide you to a better solution.